Show that the density function of $\lambda X$ is $f_{\lambda X}(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda}f_X(\frac{x}{\lambda})$.

Let a random variable $X$ have a density function $f_X$ and $\lambda$ a nonzero real number. Show that the density function of $\lambda X$ is given by $f_{\lambda X}(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda}f_X(\frac{x}{\lambda})$.

Here's what I have so far for positive $\lambda$.
For positive $\lambda$, $F_{\lambda X}$ is
$$F_{\lambda X}(x) = \mathbb{P}\{\lambda X \leq x\} = \mathbb{P}\{X \leq \frac{x}{\lambda}\}$$
Apply the definition of density function of $X$ gives
$$\mathbb{P}\{X \leq \frac{x}{\lambda}\} = \int^{\frac{x}{\lambda}}_{-\infty}f_X(t) dt$$
By change of variable $u = \lambda t$. This integral is equivalent to
$$\int^{\frac{x}{\lambda}}_{-\infty}f_X(t) dt = \int^{x}_{-\infty}f_X(\frac{u}{\lambda}) \frac{1}{\lambda}du$$
Using the definition of density function of $\lambda X$ gives
$$F_{\lambda X}(x) = \int^{x}_{-\infty}f_{\lambda X}(t) dt = \int^{x}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda} f_X(\frac{u}{\lambda})du$$
Thus, we have $f_{\lambda X}(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda} f_X(\frac{x}{\lambda})$ for positive $\lambda$.
I have two main concerns:

In the last step, I assumed that, if the integral of two functions over all intervals $(-\infty, x]$ is equal, then the two functions are equal. For continuous integrands, this is true by fundamental theorem of calculus. However, $f_{X}$ and $f_{\lambda X}$ may not be continuous. Is it still a valid argument?
How does the proof generalize for negative $\lambda$?

If necessary, a measure-theoretic explanation is prefered.

For the first problem, recall that there can be many PDFs for a random variable $X$, and the definition is just any nonnegative function that satisfies
$$\Pr(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
for all $x$. You showed that $\frac1{\lambda}f_X\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)$ is a function that satisfies this, so is a valid PDF for $\lambda X$.
For negative $\lambda$, what is given cannot be correct since it is always nonpositive. You have in general
$$f_{\lambda X}(x)=\frac{1}{|\lambda|}f_X\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)$$
It is essentially the same argument with a little change.
$$\Pr(\lambda X\le x)=\Pr\left(X\ge\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)=\int_{x/\lambda}^{\infty}f_X(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
Change of variable $u=\lambda t$ gives
$$\Pr(\lambda X\le x)=\int_{x}^{-\infty}\frac1{\lambda}f_X\left(\frac{u}{\lambda}\right)\,\mathrm du$$
which gives you the expression that I wrote earlier.
Hope this helps. :)
